# cephes math library build error

Tags: gcc, makefile, flags

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install cephes library, but I'm consistently getting an error. It says:

`sqrtelf.387:8: Error: invalid instruction suffix for push

I have looked around the web and also checked this forum and figured out, it has probably something to do with wrong compiling settings. I edited make file and it looks like this now:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -m32 -O2 -Wall -fno-builtin
LDFLAGS = -m32
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
INCS = mconf.h
AS = as
```

It still does not work. I also checked mconf.h, but I don't even know what should I change. Thanks for help.

I got the source file [here](http://www.moshier.net/) (double.zip)

Comment: Warning: that double.zip is a tarbomb; extract it in an empty folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says problematic instruction is in file `sqrtelf.387` at line 8. That is

```
pushl %ebp
```

Most likely you have 64bit toolchain; `pushl` isn't available in 64bit mode. However if you're not and you want 32 bit version, you could add `--32` to `as` flags.

To work this around you should comment out this target in makefile; in theory you could uncomment `sqrtelf.amd64` target instead, but benefits are questionable. Look for comment in makefile:

```
# Assembly language utilities.
# If the following are all commented out, the C versions
# will be used by default.
```

Comment: Ok great, it works now. I commented all the lines where the word "sqrtelf.387" is and it worked normally (although it still produced a lot of warnings). Thank you.